# Is there any usual way to imitate a return in a parfor in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

The body of a parfor-loop cannot contain a return statement.

I feel it could be convenient sometime, e.g.:

```
if matlabpool('size') == 0 % checking to see if my pool is already open
    matlabpool(2)
end

parameters = random_parameters(1000)
parfor i=1:1000
    result = do_stuff(parameters(i))
    if result < threshold
        return parameters
    end
end
```

Is there any usual way to imitate a return in a parfor?

I use Matlab R2014a on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Do you mean you want all iterations to stop once the condition is met? What if the condition is met for more then one parameter? Then the behavior is undefined, no?

Comment: @ItamarKatz  `you want all iterations to stop once the condition is met` -> Yes. `What if the condition is met for more then one parameter?` Then it's "~random", which is fine in my case.

Comment: how long does it take to execute one call to `do_stuff`? can fake it by breaking the problem into sequences of loops or `spmd` blocks but the problem is going to be the overhead from the parallel block

Comment: @transversalitycondition `do_stuff` is sometimes quite short, but not always (I use this code template in different application). Aside from the overhead, if one breaks the problem into sequences of loops or spmd blocks, isn't it a pain to save the environment variables that changed in the loop or spmd block `t` so that they can be accessed in loop  or spmd block `t+1`? Or is there a clever way?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: Using the same code for very short do_stuff and long do_stuff won't be the right choice. For very short do_stuff I would run small batches of maybe 50 inside a for loop and check it for these batches, accepting to calculate some unwanted results. For large do_stuff I would use the job submit interface to wrap each task into an individual job, achieving full control at the price of some overhead.

Comment: I think with parfor yes, spmd should make life easier. You can have one spmd block which creates variables common to all the workers and another nested within a regular for loop which uses distributed arrays to allocate batches of parameters to the workers. @Daniel is right though that the optimal solution depends on how long it takes to call do_stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I use try-catch block in such cases. Some example:

```
rng('shuffle')
try parpool('local'); end % try block to avoid reinitiation of parpool
parameters = normrnd(0,1,1000,1);
threshold=0.95;
FoundParameter=NaN;
try
    parfor iParam=1:1000
        result = sin(parameters(iParam))
        if result < threshold
            error(num2str(parameters(iParam)))
        end
    end
catch err
    FoundParameter=str2num(err.message);
end
if isnan(FoundParameter)
    fprintf('\nGood parameter was not found\n')
else
    fprintf('\nGood parameter is: %f\n',FoundParameter)
end
```

**P.S. Please, do not use i and j as iteration variables. It is bad practice in MatLab**

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I typically avoid using i and j as iteration variables, it was mostly for the sake of example :-)